# NullPointerException setting adapter in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-xml, android-listfragment

I have been at this for over 12 hours now, so perhaps stackoverflow can help me.

In my `MainActivity` I have 3 fragments which are loaded from the side navigation drawer. In one of my fragments I have a **ListView**, which I am trying to set with an `ArrayAdapter` and receives information from `data.xml`.

**Fragment class where error is occurring:**

```
public static class SongsFragment extends ListFragment  {


        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";




        public SongsFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle b){
            super.onActivityCreated(b);
            //AlbumAdapt loadAlbums = new AlbumAdapt(this.getView(), this.getActivity());


            ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.layout.fragment_item_list);
            List<AlbumModel> albums = null;

            try {
                XMLData parser = new XMLData();
                albums = parser.parse(getActivity().getAssets().open("data.xml"));
                ArrayAdapter<AlbumModel> adapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<AlbumModel>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, albums);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);

            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));

        }



        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);
        }

        public static SongsFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            SongsFragment fragment = new SongsFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            return fragment;
        }



    }
```

**Logcat seems pretty clear:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.markbratanov.myfitplayer/com.markbratanov.myfitplayer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.markbratanov.myfitplayer.MainActivity$SongsFragment.onActivityCreated(MainActivity.java:235)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1508)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The entire project is hosted on github for class references, etc: https://github.com/markbratanov/MyFitPlayer/tree/master/Player/src/main/java/com/markbratanov/myfitplayer

Any guidance/comments would be appreciated... I've tried a lot and all I want is to get this listview to work so I can move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `R.id.viewid`. Since you have a `ListFragment`

You have

```
 ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.layout.fragment_item_list);
```

Should be

```
 ListView listView = getListView();
```

Comment: `
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />`

That is my fragment view, the listview id is list, when I put 

`ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.layout.list);`

I receive **cannot resolve symbol list**

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you. will mark as answer after 6 minutes.